# Best way to make a connection to database in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

As far as I know, there is two approaches for connecting to database in Laravel.

**Approach 1:**

```
// the name of table is defined in the model file
Model_Name::WHERE(1)->get();
```

**Approach 2:**

```
DB::table('table_name')->WHERE(1)->get();
```

Ok, both work the same and they have identical results. So what's the different? Which one is better in which situation?

Anyway, when should I use which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel provides an inbuilt ORM called Eloquent which makes our interaction with the database easy. Eloquent ORM provides Active Record implementation which means that each model you create in your MVC structure corresponds to a table in your database. Here, ‘Post’ model will correspond to “posts” table. So, You can access the data in the posts table as follows

```
Post::all()          // Get all the posts 
Post::find($id)      // Find a post
Post::delete($id)    // Delete a post
```

Fluent query builder

As the name implies, It provides fluent interface to create and run database queries. The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding throughout to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings. Some of the examples are.

```
DB::table('posts')->get();                       // Get all the posts
DB::table('posts')->where('id',$id)->first();    // Find a post
DB::table('posts')->where('id',$id)->delete();   // Delete a post
```

**Pros of Eloquent**

```
You can use all Fluent functions in eloquent. But, You can’t use eloquent functions in the query builder
Eloquent model relationship
Easy to use
Code Readability
```

**Cons of Eloquent**

```
Execution time may increase little bit
In some places, Eloquent fail to compete against SQL queries for complex queries
```

**Conclusion**

Since, Both the eloquent and fluent query builder have their own pros and cons. You should use both of those based on the requirement. As many things, 80:20 rule seems to apply here. Use eloquent to take care of 80% of the work for you, and be prepared to write SQL and some persistence code for the other 20% using fluent. Don’t expect too much from eloquent or you will end up with some strange bugs and performance issues.

[Complete Reference](https://blog.sriraman.in/laravel-eloquent-vs-fluent-query-builder/)

Comment: So you suggest I have to use `Post::all()` *(eloquent)* as possible as I can,  and when it fails, then I have to use `DB::table('post')->get` *(fluent query builder)*, right?

Comment: Yeah my suggestion is this, but you can use it accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

**I prefer the first approach if performance is not an issue, because:**

Suppose you have used the second approach in 100 places of your code. Now, you want to change the table name for some specific reason. What will you do? You need to changes in 100 places where you used specific `table_name`.

```
DB::table('table_name')->where(1)->get(); //change table_name in 100 palces
```

If you use the first approach, you might have written

```
Model_Name::where(1)->get(); //no change here
```

Now, you need to change the table name, What you just have to do is, change/add the table property in your model. Something like this:

```
class Model_Name{
    protected $table = 'new_table_name'; //change table_name in one place
}
```

Nothing else to do. You are highly flexible with your table name.

**Note:** The first approach is Eloquent ORM approach and it has many facility that an `ORM` should have. On the other hand, fluent query is better performer. You can use what ever you want to. But **avoiding mixing up both approaches in a single project is a good practice I think.**

Comment: In the first approach, suppose you want to change the model name for some specific reasons. What will you do? You need to change in 100 places where you used `use App/model_name`.

Comment: Got your point, let's consider a more practical example. You may change a `users` table to `user` or `systemUser` or something like that which is very common while developing. Then the `User` model is still relevant as model name. But yes, if you want to rename your `User` model/table to `Student` that will create a problem. You need to make your hands dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Both approach are work with same result but while you use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent), will allow to code/work pretty good with relations so you can maintain code readability whereas [Fluent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) will help to run complex SQL query.

Laravel provides an built-in functionality called [ORM Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent). ORM Eloquent makes code interaction with the database easily by each model. Just you need create in your MVC structure corresponds to a DB table. Use is also very simple like:

```
Model_name::DB_interaction_functions
```

[Fluent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries) query builder provides pre-built fluent interface to create and run database queries in simple way like:

```
DB::table('table_name')->DB_interaction_functions
```

This is a simple thing but if we talk about performance of Eloquent and Fluent, Fluent is best then Eloquent. I can't test it but you can apply it.

**Summery**
Eloquent is a simple way to use in and good terms of code readability but it will take little more time to execution query. Whereas Fluent is well while execute complex SQL query.

Ref: [Laravel Eloquent vs Fluent query builder](https://blog.sriraman.in/laravel-eloquent-vs-fluent-query-builder/)

Comment: Do you mean *"Fluent is best **than** Eloquent."*, Is there a typo in your text ?

Comment: @stack: *Fluent* is best based on execution performance + handle complex query. *Eloquent* is best based on code readability and usability.